# How to fill a new dataframe column by conditional summing

Tags: r

I would like build a new variable by summing values considering multiple conditions (and an extra one, see below). Here you can see R Code until something like my current issue.

```
# The raw dataframe
area <- c("A", "A", "B", "A", "C", "B", "A", "B", "A", "C")
varclass <- c("Z1", "Z1", "Z1", "Z2", "Z1", "Z1", "Z2", "Z1", "Z2", "Z2")
count <- c(45, 56, 2, 8, 345, 3, 98, 2, 6, 9)

df1 <- data.frame(area,
                  varclass,
                  count,
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df1
# See how df1 looks like...
#    area varclass count
#1     A       Z1    45
#2     A       Z1    56
#3     B       Z1     2
#4     A       Z2     8
#5     C       Z1   345
#6     B       Z1     3
#7     A       Z2    98
#8     B       Z1     2
#9     A       Z2     6
#10    C       Z2     9

# Building the final dataframe

df2 <- data.frame(unique(df1$area),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(df2)[1] <- "area"
# See how df2 looks like...
#   area
#1    A
#2    B
#3    C 

# The new variable to build

df2$Z1_sum <- sum(df1[df1$varclass == "Z1" & df1$area == df2$area,]$count)
# doesn't work

# See what I hope
#   area  Z1_sum
#1    A     101
#2    B      7
#3    C     345
```

As you can see in the last line, I would like building a new variable, Z1_sum, in the df2 database. Z1_sum is the sum of count from the df1 database where `varclass = "Z1"` and `df1$area` meet the value of `df2$area` current row (in MS Excel, that means using a LC1 or $A2 cell id).

Please, consider the fact that I'm not looking for solutions involving to directly build df2 from df1 by using a group by condition or the `dcast` function... I only want a formula which allow me to return correct values in my new column. It's my extra condition. Why? It's because I have next to build other variables with most sophisticated formulas than just a sum. By understanding how make such conditional operations, I hope move on...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
df2 <- setNames(
                aggregate(
                          count ~ area,
                          df1[df1$varclass == "Z1", ],
                          sum
                          ),
                c("area", "Z1_sum")
               )
df2
  area Z1_sum
1    A    101
2    B      7
3    C    345
```

or

```
df2$Z1_sum <- aggregate(count ~ area, df1[df1$varclass == "Z1", ], sum)$count
```

---

*Edit to address your comment.*

Try with:

```
df2 <- aggregate(
                 count ~ area + varclass,
                 df1,
                 sum
                )
```

that will give you your data in the "long" format:

```
df2
  area varclass count
1    A       Z1   101
2    B       Z1     7
3    C       Z1   345
4    A       Z2   112
5    C       Z2     9
```

Now you need to reshape it to the "wide" format using something like:

```
df2 <- xtabs(count ~ area + varclass, df2)
    varclass
area  Z1  Z2
   A 101 112
   B   7   0
   C 345   9
```

or:

```
df2 <- reshape(df2, idvar = "area", timevar = "varclass", direction = "wide")
  area count.Z1 count.Z2
1    A      101      112
2    B        7       NA
3    C      345        9
```

Comment: Thank you. The first proposal works fine but with the same limit than Roman's one. Your second one seems to me accurate but doesn't work with my dataset. I get the error message : "Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, AZ_tx, value = c(96L, 24L, 84L, 12L,  :  replacement has 105 rows, data has 322".

Comment: It's true. Is it possible to overcome it? Other ideas? I initially rather thinking to add an argument like "& df1$area == ??" where ?? give the relative value of df2$area considering the output row...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your edit. It's very nice. However, I don't want reshape/change the dataframe because I want at the end filling new columns with more sophisticated operations. Admitting that I would like create in one step "newvar2" with the result of dividing the Z1_sum by Z2_sum and multiplied by 100...

Answer (score 0):

Just subset based on whichever Z* you want counted in your final sum.

```
df1Z1 <- df1[df1$varclass %in% c("Z1"), ]
aggregate(count ~ area, data = df1Z1, FUN = sum)

  area count
1    A   101
2    B     7
3    C   345
```

Comment: Thanks Roman. That works fine for one shot but I don't know how I can filling my dataframe df2 with more than one new column. Considering that Z1_sum is one of many new columns (Z2_sum and so on) that I want to fill in a df2 dataframe, with agregate function it seems to me that I have to build many intermediate dataframes and merge it later all in one... I am wrong about that?

Answer (score 0):

You can get your desired result using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- group_by(df1, area) %>% 
  filter(varclass == "Z1") %>% 
  summarize(Z1_sum = sum(count)) %>% 
df2
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>    area Z1_sum
#>   <chr>  <dbl>
#> 1     A    101
#> 2     B      7
#> 3     C    345
```

The `dplyr` verbs should be pretty explanatory, and the `%>%` is the pipe operating, taking the output from one function and making it the first input to the next. `group_by` here groups by the column `area` so when we calculate the sum (in `summarize`) it's the sum for each area group. The `filter` subsets the data.

Comment: Thanks. The package dplyr ist great!